# Matlab. How to compute trace of exterior product?

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

I want to compute the trace of an n-fold exterior product of a matrix in Matlab. For the definition of the exterior product, please refer to [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_determinant#Definition) and so I am interested in computing the Taylor coefficients in the expansion of the determinant. Is this already implemented in Matlab or do I have to do anything new?

Comment: You'll have to make a better effort at explaining your question... Maybe include a small example with input and desired output

Comment: As Luis has said, please add more explanation of what you want to achieve. Please also note that most of your audiences are merely programmers with limited math skills... so please bear with us :)